# Show that $W \subset\text{span}\{1, x^2 , −3x + x^3 , x^4 , −5x + x^5 \}$ and that $\text{span} \{1, x^2 , −3x + x^3 , x^4 , −5x + x^5 \}\subset W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given that $W = \{p ∈ \Pi_5(\Omega) \mid p'(−1) + p'(1) = 0\}$. Please help I'm really stuck on this question. I have no clue how to do it. All I know is that I need to multiply by constants.

I would really really appreciate your help.

Comment: You’ve already asked this in two separate questions previously.

Comment: and im still not getting an adequate answer, i already deleted my previous question

Comment: So I guess $\Pi_5(\Omega)$ is the set of polynomials with real coefficients and degree at most $5$?

Comment: The second half is trivial. For the first half take the polynomial as $a_5x^5+\dots+a_0$. It is in $W$ iff $5a_5+3a_3+a_1=0$. Isn't it obvious that this is spanned by the given polynomials?

Comment: It’s bad form to repost questions just because you don’t like the answers you’re getting.